# Problem with mapping list of images inside the products list using woocommerce api in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, woocommerce

```
class ProductModel {
  late String name;
  late int id;
  late String status;
  late String price;
  late List<Images> images;

  ProductModel(
    this.name,
    this.id,
    this.status,
    this.images,
    this.price,
  );

  ProductModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    id = json['id'];
    status = json['status'];
    //images = json['images'];
    images = json['image'];
    if (json['images'] != null) {
      images = new List<Images>(); // error on List<Images>() "The default 'List' constructor //isn't available when null safety is enabled.

      json['images'].forEach((v) {
        images.add(new Images.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    price = json['price'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['status'] = this.status;
    if (this.images != null) {
      data['images'] = this.images.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['price'] = this.price;
    return data;
  }
}

// ignore: camel_case_types
class Images {
  late int id;
  late String src;
  late String title;

  Images({
    this.id = 0,
    this.src = "",
    this.title = "",
  });

  Images.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    src = json['src'];
    title = json['title'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['src'] = this.src;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    return data;
  }
}
```

I want to list the products of my Woocommerce site in the Flutter app, But getting an error mentioned in the code, please help. Please guide me the best way to model the JSON into Dart class. Tried converting online using https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/ but this gives lots of errors

Comment: try this website Quicktype => https://app.quicktype.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it seems you are initializing the List incorrectly.

It should be:

```dart
images = <Images>[];
```

Also, you do not need to initialize with the `new` keyword anymore.

Comment: That works thank u.. can you tell me how can I access the only first record "src" of the Images list inside a ListView.builder using snapshot.data?

Comment: in the itemCount field pass `images.length` and in the builder reference it using images[index]